# Android tab with gridview lags in switch

Tags: android, gridview, imagedownload

I have 3 tabs in one of my android guis and the second one contains one [gridview](/questions/tagged/gridview) which downloads images from the internet! The problem is that when I switch between the tabs and I pass through the gridview I see a non user-friendly lag. How can I avoid this? I want a smooth behavior. Is it good solution to pause the downloads in every tab switch and resume them after the change?

Answer (score 0):

What are you using to download the images and put them into the GridView? I have implemented functionality similar to yours (with a gridView being the large portion of one of the tabs). You should use a rather efficient tool called the [UniversalImageLoader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader). It will lazy load the GridView and should eliminate any semblance of a lag if you implement caching correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I use the code from [android-developers](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html). it uses the cache and I think that it using it very efficient as it is in display bitmaps efficient section. My thought about having a smoother behavior is to pause download work every time I switch tab and resume when the switch have been made!